# Huawei phone write to external storage fails even that the permission added to the manifest

Tags: android, kotlin

Hey I have developed an app that saves a picture to external storage using MediaStore library.

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                contentResolver,
                takenImage,
                imgName,
                "Image Saved"
            )
```

The function work on Samsung A30 and Xiomi devices however when testing on Huawei p90 it fails(not saving the image) and throwing permission denial exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=15830, uid=10438 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

However I do have the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest, when the is running I am prompted with a permission request (dealing with the runtime permission via CameraKit function and package)

Anything I missed?

Comment: Please tell the Android version of the used phones.

Comment: @blackapps android 10 on both :/

Comment: `Anything I missed?` Yes. A lot of posts here where storage permissions on Android 10/Q were solved with requesting legacy external storage in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in manifest for the desired permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I have written that I do have this permission and the process works on other phones.

Comment: @error86 have you managed to fix that issue maybe?